# How to load balance celery tasks across several servers?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I'm running celery on multiple servers, each with a concurrency of 2 or more and  I want to load balance celery tasks so that the server that has the lowest CPU usage can process my celery tasks.

For example, lets say I have 2 servers (A and B), each with a concurrency of 2, if I have 2 tasks in the queue, I want A to process one task and B to process the other. But currently its possible that the first process on A will execute one task and the second process on A will execute the second task while B is sitting idle.

Is there a simple way, by means of celery extensions or config, that I can route tasks to the server with lowest CPU usage?

Comment: did you find any solution for this..

Answer (score 3):

Best option is to use `celery.send_task` from the producing server, then deploy the workers onto `n` instances. The workers can then be run as @ealeon mentioned, using `celery -A proj worker -l info -Ofair`. 

This way, load will be distributed across all servers without having to have the codebase present on the consuming servers.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

"http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#guide-optimizing
You can disable this prefetching behavior by enabling the -Ofair worker option:

$ celery -A proj worker -l info -Ofair"

Comment: -O fair doesn't do much to balance across servers specifically, it's only about balancing across processes on the same node. If you have 4 workers per node you could easily end up with a case where one node has 4 jobs running and other nodes are totally idle.